# Hover Drop-down menu problems in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with a hovered menu in IE7, in a site I'm developing now. It works fine on a compliant browser (eg. Firefox).

This is the link: http://kaplareva.com/elet-ter-WP/

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id ="menu-maincontent">
<h2>Társas kapcsolatok</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Egyedül</a> | 
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Szingli</a> | </li> 
<li><a href="#">Gyász</a> | </li> 
<li><a href="#">Egyedülálló szülő</a></li> 
</ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Párkapcsolat</a> | 
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Párterápia</a> | </li> 
<li><a href="#">Párkapcsolat zavarai</a></li> 
</ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Család</a> | 
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Családterápia</a></li> 
</ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Szülő-gyerek</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Anya-gyerek kapcsolat</a> | </li> 
<li><a href="#">Apával való kapcsolat</a></li> 
</ul>
</li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menu-maincontent ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: 'GiacomoMedium',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

#menu-maincontent ul li ul { 
    display: none;
    font-size: 10pt;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: white;
}

#menu-maincontent ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any help please? Sorry if similar case is already solved somewhere else, but i couldn't find an appropriate solution.

Best Regards,
gas

Comment: I do not see a problem in my browser window. Describe what it is that you wish to change/fix.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. So, the menu on the top of the right frame has a sub-menu which shows on hover, and it works fine on FF, but in IE7 the menu items show in the same line, and not below, like it should. Also, the bottom seems a bit cropped off in IE7.

Comment: This site might help: http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tutorials/horizontal-drop-down-menu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `<br>` behind the `|` in your menu, so the embedded ul will be forced to go to new line.

Works for me in IE7.

Comment: Great, thank you, it solved the problem! 
I hope I can replicate the addition of br tags only for the top level menu in wordpress though... Do you know how can it be done with wp_list_categories, that it adds the br tags only for the top level items, but not the bottom? Or is it better done with jQuery?

Comment: You managed to add the '|' character in the top level menu, no? can't you just add the br in the same way?

Comment: It's still in html+css design stage... anyway, I'll check the codex when I came to the point of transferring the design to WP.

Comment: I would highly suggest you avoid `|` chars in navigation. It is not a semantic element or meant for format/layout details. it's merely an ascii char that fudges up people with text readers. It also causes formatting issues if you ever change typography. Also, be sure to close your BR tag like this `<br />` for validation reasons.